# Problema con exportar los datos a un excel, no guardo los datos en el excel lo deja en blanco

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes les comento me gustaría exportar los datos que arroja el programa a un excel  pero no lo consigo, cuando abro el excel no aparecen datos, aquí  dejo a mi código...

// metodo para guardar los datos en excel

```
 private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveExcel(progressBar1, grd);

    }



    private void saveExcel(ProgressBar pBar, DataGridView grd)
    {


        SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
        fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";

        if (pBar != null)
        {
            pBar.Maximum = grd.RowCount;
            pBar.Value = 0;
            if (!pBar.Visible) pBar.Visible = true;
        }
        if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
            aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
            hoja_trabajo =
                (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabajo
            for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
                pBar.Value += 1;
            }
            libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
            libros_trabajo.Close(true);
            aplicacion.Quit();
        }

        if (pBar != null)
        {
            pBar.Value = 0;
            pBar.Visible = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Datos exportados correctamente");

        }


    }
```

// método para extraer información de procesador

```
 DataGridView grd = new DataGridView();


    private void MuestraInformacion(String Key)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();


        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Propiedad");
        listView1.Columns.Add("Valor");

        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from " + Key);
            foreach (ManagementObject objeto in searcher.Get())
            {

                string grupo = objeto["Name"].ToString();
                listView1.Groups.Add(grupo, grupo);

                if (objeto.Properties.Count <= 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("La Información No Está Disponible", "No Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    return;
                }



                ListViewItem listViewItem1 = null;
                foreach (PropertyData PropiedadObjeto in objeto.Properties)
                {
                    listViewItem1 = new ListViewItem(PropiedadObjeto.Name);
                    if (PropiedadObjeto.Value != null && PropiedadObjeto.Value.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        listViewItem1.SubItems.Add(PropiedadObjeto.Value.ToString());
                    }

                    listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem1);
                    listView1.Groups[grupo].Items.Add(listViewItem1);

                }

                grd.DataSource = listViewItem1;

            }
```

// metodo para del boton

```
          private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

         saveExcel(progressBar1, grd);




       }
```

Comment: Has intentado CSV?

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en el codigo, puedes evaluar que la ejecucion ingresa dentro del for ? Tambien observo que creas la instancia del DataGridView, pero no asignas esta a la coleccion de controles del form para visualizar el grid